# Can You Have A Return And A Formula In A Ternary?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

```
   public boolean hasOne(int n) {
      while(n != 0) {
         (n % 10 == 1)? return true : n /= 10;

      }

      return false;
  }
```

I'm trying to check if there is a "1" in the number sent.

Comment: No and I'm sure the compiler will tell you that there's syntax error.

Comment: And just for code golfing/prettiness purposes: `while (n != 0 && n % 10 != 1) n /= 10; return n != 0;`

Comment: Hint: programming is first and foremost about you trying things yourself. Meaning: instead of first writing code, to then ask others "does this work" ... try it yourself. Ideally, think upfront what you expect to happen. See what happens. Then think "why is it different" ... and then, when you thought about that hard, maybe then ask others to fill the gaps. But going first "here is my code, somebody else me what it does" ... that is like learning to ride the bicycle by asking another person what happens when you hit the brakes to hard or so.

Answer (score 3):

That makes no sense.

First of all, you have to understand the difference between a 'statement' and an 'expression'.

`return` is a statement, possibly containing an expression after the keyword.

The conditional operator (its proper name, not "the operator with three operands") is used in an expression.

What you have written is:

```
<expression> ?  <statement> : <expression>
```

-or-

```
<expression> ?  <statement> : <statement>
```

(the second expression could be an expression statement).

There is no such syntax in Java.  What you want is expressed with an 'if` statement, simply and clearly.

```
 if (n % 10 == 1)
     return true;
 else
     n /= 10;
```

An expression using the conditional operator is not interchangeable with an if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.  A ternary operation is expected to return a value based on a condition.  But a return statement does not return a value outside of it's normal behavior when returning from method calls.  But to do what you want you can do the following:

```
public boolean hasOne(int n) {
   return Integer.toString(n).contains("1");
}
```

or

```
public static boolean hasOne(int n) {
    // in case it's negative
    n = Math.abs(n);

    while (n%10 > 1) {
        n/=10;
    }
    return  n == 1;
}
```

You can read about the [Conditional Operator aka Ternary Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) here.